# Programmatically add residuals by group as new column

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to add columns to lists in a for loop and I've tried `$` notation and the following reprex with no success. What's the approach for base R here?

```r
# selected
month = c(5, 6)

# list of models
models = lapply(setNames(month, paste0("m", month)), function(x) {
    lm(Temp ~ Ozone, subset(airquality, Month == x))
})

# adding residuals of every model to airquality dataset
airquality$residuals = NA

for (model in names(models)) {
    temp = sub("m", "", model)
    data = within(airquality, {
        residuals = ifelse(
            Month == temp,
            models[model][, "residuals"],
            residuals
        )
    })
}
#> Error in models[model][, "residuals"]: número incorreto de dimensões
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refrain from using `within` in a programmatic approach and stick to standard evaluation:

```r
month = c(5, 6)

# list of models
models = lapply(setNames(month, paste0("m", month)), function(x) {
    lm(Temp ~ Ozone, subset(airquality, Month == x))
})

airquality$residuals = NA

for (model in names(models)) {

    temp = as.integer(sub("m", "", model))
    
    airquality[airquality$Month == temp & !is.na(airquality$Ozone),]$residuals <- models[[model]]$residuals

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! What's the catch with within()? I've noted that using within() I've got the df reordered (I guess) causing residuals assigned to the wrong rows, which is catastrophic.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it less cumbersome using `by`. First, rather than looping over the months, `subset` to a smaller data frame,

```
airquality2 <- subset(airquality, Month %in% c(5, 6))
```

then, run the regression on the data split `by` the selected months and extract the residuals. They are named by their row numbers which allows you to add them on correct positions using the bracket function `` `[<-` ``. Finally just `rbind`.

```
airquality2 <- by(airquality, airquality$Month, \(x) {
  resid <- lm(Temp ~ Ozone, x)$resid
  x[names(resid), 'residuals'] <- resid
  x
}) |> do.call(what=rbind)

head(airquality2)
#     Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day residuals
# 5.1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1 -2.562432
# 5.2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2  3.251984
# 5.3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3  9.161183
# 5.4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4 -3.816117
# 5.5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5        NA
# 5.6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6 -1.444950
```

If for some reason you need it, you may merge it back to the rest of the data.

```
airquality <- merge(airquality, airquality2)
```